# How can i resolve the enable the extensions in php.ini?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I am trying to install voyager package in Laravel application (The project is created on the WAPP Stack in Alibaba Cloud ECS instance) it throws me a like it is unable to install the package, Please enable the extensions in the php.ini but it is already enabled. Please help me to resolve this... Thanks in advance...

[image]

Comment: Hi I think you need to enable the fileinfo PHP extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the error is a false-positive and you are sure the `fileinfo` PHP extension is really both, installed and enabled, you can force the composer installation in two ways:

1. You can use the `--ignore-platform-reqs` option when calling `composer install`. It will ignore dependencies that start with `ext-`, meaning it will not check if they are resolvable. It will also not check the available PHP version.
2. You can simulate an environment to composer by adding a special `platform` configuration in your `composer.json` under the `config` key:

   ```
   {
      ... other composer settings ...
      "config": {
        "platform": {
           "ext-fileinfo": "1.0"
        }
      }
   }
   ```